# tkinterモジュールと外部ファイルの連携

Tags: python

tkinterモジュールのテキストボックス内に、ユーザ側に値を入れてもらい、その値を別ファイルの特定の変数に代入する方法を知りたいです。

exe化して、外部ファイルの実行など試してみましたが、外部ファイル内の変数に代入するのができないです。

Comment: 短い文章で大まかな内容を記述されただけでは、何が問題なのか分からないと思われます。こちらのヘルプ記事を参考に質問内容を詳細化してみてください。[良い質問をするには？](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), [再現可能な短いサンプルコードの書き方](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: exe化したら出来なくなった、ということでしょうか？また「外部ファイル内の変数」とは何を意味していますか？

Comment: tkinterの表示・入力・値取得と、ファイルへの代入(書き換え)は別々の独立した処理ですね。アプリケーションを作る目的としての連携ではあっても、tkinterの何かの機能で処理するものでは無いでしょう。やりたい事や発生している課題の明確化・詳細化を行ってください。こちらの記事などを参考に。[【Python】テキストボックス(Tkinter.Entry)の作成・出力・入力](https://pg-chain.com/python-tkinter-entry), [Python Tkinter Entry()とStringVar()について](https://qiita.com/ab-boy_ringo/items/51242a3150365ec81106), [Pythonで設定ファイルを作って操作する...](https://kaibutsusyain.com/how-to-create-and-operate-a-configuration-file-in-python/), [pythonプログラムにおける設定ファイル管理モジュール...](https://qiita.com/mimitaro/items/3506a444f325c6f980b2), [PythonでJSONファイル...](https://mayumega.site/prog/py_json_wra/)

Comment: 実行環境および外部ファイルの保存先に依存しますが、アンチウィルスソフトによっては、ファイルの書き換えを防止する機能があり、書き換えた内容を強引に元に戻される（反映されない）場合があります。試してみたソースコードを記載してもらうと何がしたいか分かり易いのですが。